# In mySQL, Is it possible to SELECT from two tables and merge the columns?

Tags: database, mysql, sql

If I have two tables in mysql that have similar columns...

```
TABLEA
  id
  name
  somefield1

TABLEB 
  id
  name
  somefield1
  somefield2
```

How do I structure a SELECT statement so that I can SELECT from both tables simultaneously, and have the result sets merged for the columns that are the same?

So for example, I am hoping to do something like...

```
SELECT name, somefield1 FROM TABLEA, TABLEB WHERE name="mooseburgers";
```

...and have the name, and somefield1 columns from both tables merged together in the result set.

Thank-you for your help!

Sample output appended because question unclear:

I want the rows from table1 and the rows from table2 appended in the resultset.  For example  if the tables contain

```
TABLEA
id(1) name(zoot) somefield(suit)

TABLEB
id(1) name(zoot) somefield(flute)

The resultet would look like:

name     |     somefield1
zoot           suit
zoot           flute
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Please provide sample output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine columns from both tables using (id,name) as the joining criteria with:

```
select
    a.id                               as id,
    a.name                             as name,
    a.somefield1 || ' ' || b.somefied1 as somefield1
from tablea a, tableb b
where a.id   = b.id
  and a.name = b.name
  and b.name = 'mooseburgers';
```

If you want to join on just the (id) and combine the name and somefield1 columns:

```
select
    a.id                               as id,
    a.name || ' ' || b.name            as name,
    a.somefield1 || ' ' || b.somefied1 as somefield1
from tablea a, tableb b
where a.id   = b.id
  and b.name = 'mooseburgers';
```

Although I have to admit this is a rather unusual way of doing things. I assume you have your reasons however :-)

If I've misunderstood your question and you just want a more conventional union of the two tables, use something like:

```
select id, name, somefield1, '' as somefield2 from tablea where name = 'mooseburgers'
union all
select id, name, somefield1, somefield2 from tableb where name = 'mooseburgers'
```

This won't *combine* rows but will instead just append the rows from the two queries. Use `union` on its own if you want to remove duplicate rows but, if you're certain there are no duplicates or you don't want them removed, `union all` is often more efficient.

---

Based on your edit, the actual query would be:

```
select name, somefield1 from tablea where name = 'zoot'
union all
select name, somefield1 from tableb where name = 'zoot'
```

(or `union` if you don't want duplicates where `a.name==b.name=='zoot'` and `a.somefield1==b.somefield1`).

Comment: Thank-you.  Sorry if my question was unclear.  Yes, I just want to append the rows from the two tables.  And be sure that the column somefield1 from Table1 and somefield1 from Table2 both appear under the single column somefield 1 in the resultset.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by merge, but you can [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) the results:

```
SELECT id, name, somefield1 FROM TABLEA WHERE name="mooseburgers"
union all
SELECT id, name, somefield1 FROM TABLEB WHERE name="mooseburgers";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps mean

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.name, tableA.somefield1
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.name = tableB.name AND tableA.name="mooseburgers"
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by merge, here's a possible solution.

```
Select id,name,somefield1 from TableA
WHERE Name ='mooseburgers'
UNION
Select id,name,somefield1 from TableB
WHERE Name ='mooseburgers'
```

Will allow you to show results from both tables with the results merged into 1 table.